# Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/wheezy/updates/Release

Tags: debian, apt, package-management

I am trying to run a `sudo apt-get update` command, my current distro is Debian Wheezy, and I am getting this error when I try to run the command :

```
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/wheezy/updates/Release
Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-mipsel/Packages' in Release file
(Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
```

However when I take a look at the `sources.list` file it seems to be fine :

```
deb http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy main
deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy main

deb http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy-updates main
deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy-updates main

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
```

Answer (score 5):

That's because Debian 7 is now on [long-term support](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS/Using), and security support is only available on `i386`, `amd64`, `armel` and `armhf`. There is no `mipsel` security support any more on Debian 7, you should upgrade to Debian 8.

Comment: Do the bad guys know they are *not* supposed to attack Debian 7 MIPS because its not supported? What happns when a board does not have an OEM'd Debian 8 image?

Comment: @jww if someone needs LTS on Debian 7 on MIPS, it might be possible to [sponsor it](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS/Funding)... If that's not acceptable, you can always ask for a refund for Debian ;-).